# fortran user defined type not found when type name overloaded as the constructor

Tags: oop, constructor, fortran

I wrote some codes in a file like this

```
module ModuleBasicGeometry4
    ...
    type TPoint
      ...
    end type TPoint

    interface TPoint
      module procedure :: TPointInit1,TPointInit2
    end interface TPoint

    contains
        ...
end module ModuleBasicGeometry4
```

In another file, I want to use my user-defined derived type TPoint. I just used the use statement:

```
... 
use ModuleBasicGeomentry4
type(TPoint) :: ...
...
```

However, when I compile these files with ifort2013_sp1.3.174, it told me that TPoint is not a   derived type name, and if I deleted the interface statement in the first file, everything was OK. It seems that the interface statement masks the type statement since they have the same name. More weirdly, I aslo defined many other derived types and the corresponding interfaces as their constructors in the same first file, and they all work OK. So what leads to this odd problem?

P.S.
I think I found some causes but I don't know why. It is not true that I said other types work Ok. In the second file, since I need some procedure pointers, I wrote something like this

```
...
interface
  ... function ...
      use MoudleBasicGeometry4
      ...
  end function ...
end interface
...
```

I found that only those types that are used before this interface statement work well. As long as the types defined in the first file are used after this interface statement, the ifort compiler will give the error message: "This is not a derived type name." What's more , if I delete the use ModuleBasicGeometry4 statement in the above interface statement, evetything is also OK. Could someone explain why and tell me how to solve this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Fortran 2003 you con use (inside interfaces) the `IMPORT` statement for importing entities that are accessible outside the interface, this way you can substitute the `USE` statement that seems to be problematic in this case

I tried to reproduce your code and the following compiles correctly with gfortran-4.8.

MODULE:

```
module ModuleBasicGeomentry4
  implicit none
  type TPoint
     integer :: a
     integer :: b
   end type TPoint

   interface TPoint
     module procedure :: TPointInit1,TPointInit2
   end interface TPoint

   contains
     function TPointInit1(a) result(point)
        integer, intent(in)  :: a
        type(TPoint)         :: point
        point%a = a
        point%b = a
     end function
      function TPointInit2(a,b) result(point)
        integer, intent(in)  :: a,b
        type(TPoint)         :: point
        point%a = a
        point%b = b
     end function
end module ModuleBasicGeomentry4
```

MAIN:

```
PROGRAM main
  use ModuleBasicGeomentry4, only : Tpoint
  implicit none

  type(Tpoint) :: point1
  interface
     integer function foo(point)
        import Tpoint
        type(Tpoint)     :: point
     end function
  end interface
  type(Tpoint)   :: point2  

  point1 = Tpoint(1)
  point2 = Tpoint(1,2)

  print*, foo(point1)
  print*, foo(point2)
END PROGRAM main

integer function foo(point)
  use ModuleBasicGeomentry4 , only : Tpoint
  type(Tpoint)     :: point
  foo = point%a + point%b
end function
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does work in your case with ifort. Unfortinately, it didn't work in my case. The difference is that my second file is also a moudle. When I replace the problematic use statement with import statement to use those derived types defined in the first file, the import statement itself seems not to cuase any error, but when I use the imported type to declare variables, the compiler tells "This derived type name has not been declared." However, those typed defined in the same second file can be properly imported and used.

Comment: Without your actual code, I can not tell you more but to compile with "-warn all".

Comment: I don't know what to say...It seems suddenly everything is Ok with the import statement. Thank you very much.